# how to grant permissions on xiaomi

Tags: android, permissions, android-permissions, xiaomi

I'm developing an app with minSdk 26 and target 33. The problem is that in samsung (s20 ultra with android 13) the dialog for permissions runs great, but in a poco x3 (MIUI Global 12.5.8.0) the permission don't work and I don't know why.

I'm using the next class to check permissions (notification and files permissions)

```
class PermissionManager<T : Activity>(private val activity: T) : DefaultLifecycleObserver {

    private lateinit var castedContext: AppCompatActivity

    private val notificationPermission = if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.TIRAMISU) {
        arrayOf(Manifest.permission.POST_NOTIFICATIONS)
    } else {
        arrayOf<String>()
    }

    private val filePermissions = if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.TIRAMISU) {
        arrayOf(
            Manifest.permission.READ_MEDIA_AUDIO,
            Manifest.permission.READ_MEDIA_IMAGES,
            Manifest.permission.READ_MEDIA_VIDEO
        )
    } else {
        arrayOf(
            Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,
            Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
        )
    }

    init {
        when (activity) {
            is AppCompatActivity -> {
                castedContext = activity
            }
            is FragmentActivity -> {
                castedContext = activity as AppCompatActivity
            }
            else -> {
                throw IllegalArgumentException("Activity must be of type AppCompatActivity or FragmentActivity")
            }
        }

    }

    private var onPermissionsGranted: (() -> Unit)? = null
    private var onPermissionsDenied: (() -> Unit)? = null

    fun requestFilePermissions(
        onGranted: (() -> Unit)? = null,
        onDenied: (() -> Unit)? = null
    ) {
        onPermissionsGranted = onGranted
        onPermissionsDenied = onDenied

        val grantedPermissions = mutableListOf<String>()

        for (permission in filePermissions) {
            val result = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(activity, permission)
            if (result == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                grantedPermissions.add(permission)
            }
        }

        if (grantedPermissions.size == filePermissions.size) {
            // Todos los permisos ya se concedieron, llama al callback
            onPermissionsGranted?.invoke()
        } else {
            // Al menos un permiso no se concedió, solicita permisos
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(activity, filePermissions, 0)
        }
    }

    fun requestNotificationPermission(
        onGranted: (() -> Unit)? = null,
        onDenied: (() -> Unit)? = null
    ) {
        onPermissionsGranted = onGranted
        onPermissionsDenied = onDenied


        val grantedPermissions = mutableListOf<String>()

        for (permission in notificationPermission) {
            val result = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(activity, permission)
            if (result == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                grantedPermissions.add(permission)
            }
        }

        if (grantedPermissions.size == notificationPermission.size) {
            // Todos los permisos ya se concedieron, llama al callback
            onPermissionsGranted?.invoke()
        } else {
            // Al menos un permiso no se concedió, solicita permisos
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(activity, notificationPermission, 0)
        }

    }

    fun requestAllPermissions(
        onGranted: (() -> Unit)? = null,
        onDenied: (() -> Unit)? = null
    ) {
        onPermissionsGranted = onGranted
        onPermissionsDenied = onDenied

        val permissions = notificationPermission + filePermissions

        val grantedPermissions = mutableListOf<String>()

        for (permission in permissions) {
            val result = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(activity, permission)
            if (result == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                grantedPermissions.add(permission)
            }
        }

        if (grantedPermissions.size == permissions.size) {
            // Todos los permisos ya se concedieron, llama al callback
            onPermissionsGranted?.invoke()
        } else {
            // Al menos un permiso no se concedió, solicita permisos
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(activity, permissions, 0)
        }
    }

    fun onRequestPermissionsResult(
        requestCode: Int,
        permissions: Array<out String>,
        grantResults: IntArray
    ) {
        if (requestCode == 0) {
            val allPermissionsGranted = grantResults.all { it == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED }
            if (!allPermissionsGranted) {
                showPermissionDeniedMessage()
                onPermissionsDenied?.invoke()
            }
        }
    }

    private fun showPermissionDeniedMessage() {

        DialogUtils.showAlertDialog(
            castedContext,
            castedContext.getString(R.string.zp_read_permissions_denied_title),
            castedContext.getString(R.string.zp_read_permissions_denied_message),
            castedContext.getString(R.string.zp_read_permissions_denied_retry),
            onPositiveButtonClick = {
                // Volver a solicitar todos los permisos
                requestAllPermissions(
                    onGranted = {
                        // Los permisos se concedieron después de volver a solicitarlos
                        // Puedes realizar acciones adicionales aquí si es necesario.
                        onPermissionsGranted?.invoke()
                    },
                    onDenied = {
                        // Los permisos se volvieron a denegar después de volver a solicitarlos
                        showPermissionDeniedMessage()
                    }
                )
            },
            castedContext.getString(R.string.zp_read_permissions_denied_exit),
            onNegativeButtonClick = {
                // Finalizar la aplicación
                castedContext.finishAffinity()
            }
        )
    }

}
```

I'm doing the init of the class in a baseactivity with.

```
permissionManager = PermissionManager(this)
```

and overriding the method onRequestPermissionsResult of the activity

```
override fun onRequestPermissionsResult(
    requestCode: Int,
    permissions: Array<out String>,
    grantResults: IntArray
) {
    super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults)

    permissionManager.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults)

}
```

later in a fragment (for example), I can use the next method:

```
fun checkPermissions() {

    mainActivity?.let {
        it.permissionManager.requestAllPermissions(onGranted = {
            // All permissons granted
        }, onDenied = {
            // Permissions denied. PermissionManager handles this behavior
        })
    }

}
```

this is my manifest file

```
...
 <!-- Required only if your app needs to access images or photos that other apps created. -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.POST_NOTIFICATIONS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_MEDIA_IMAGES" />

    <!-- Required only if your app needs to access videos that other apps created. -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_MEDIA_VIDEO" />

    <!-- Required only if your app needs to access audio files that other apps created. -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_MEDIA_AUDIO" />

    <!-- If your app doesn't need to access media files that other apps created, set the "maxSdkVersion" attribute to "28" instead. -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"
        android:maxSdkVersion="32" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"
        android:maxSdkVersion="28" />

    <application
        android:name="es.victormartin.signat"
        android:allowBackup="false"
        android:label="${appLabel}"
        android:icon="${appIcon}"
        android:networkSecurityConfig="@xml/network_security_config"
        android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"
        android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
        android:dataExtractionRules="@xml/data_extraction_rules"
        tools:replace="android:allowBackup"
        tools:ignore="DataExtractionRules,UnusedAttribute">
...
```

As I said, on samsung runs, but in xioami not.

**UPDATE:**

I think that changing permissions to this (without specifiying api levels) fix the problem, at the moment.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```